# passing docker .env variables to nginx site configurations

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables

from docker-compose.yml:

```
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
```

inside nginx/sites there are a bunch of `.conf` files for different sites. I'd like to pass variables from the docker `.env` file to these configuration files. I've seen that [you can use `.template` for the main `nginx.conf`](https://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf) file, but what about the sites-available configuration files? Is there any way to pass variables to them?